# Mazda 3 Rear Sway Bar Bushing Replacement

Tags: suspension, mazda

I'm trying to replace the rear sway bar bushings in my Mazda 3. I have the disassembly manual, and it instructed me on how to remove and replace the bushings, but one of the things it doesn't cover is how to put the bushings back onto the sway bar once they have been removed.

Specifically, I can't seem to get the bushings to compress enough to get the D bracket back onto the bushing. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bushings are usually split.  You slide the the bushing over the bar with the flat side to the vehicle.  There may be a special place on the bar where the bushing will mate properly, almost like an indentation.  The split should fully close.  Did you get the split part of the bushing to fully close or not?

Once in place, the D-bracket should nestle into place around the rounded part of the bushing.  There should be a small gap if any between the bracket and the vehicle.  Are you sure you have the bushing the right way around?

Comment: This is the solution, but I should warn those looking to do this that getting the bushing on the bar was easy, but getting the D-bracket on the bushing was much more difficult. It's almost like the new bushings are expanded when compared to the one(s) I took off the car. I had to use a bench vise to get them into position.